# Unable to create a user with password via ssh

Tags: command-line, ssh, password, users

I tried to create a user with password via ssh (with root permission) like this:

```
ssh root@123.45.6.7 useradd -p $(openssl passwd -1 1234) newuser
```

By doing so, I could successfully create an account named `newuser`, but I couldn't login with the expected password (which is `1234`)

It makes no difference if I add double quotes:

```
ssh root@123.45.6.7 "useradd -p $(openssl passwd -1 1234) newuser"
```

And then I was wondering if I can generate hashed password and save it as a variable locally, but still with no luck.

```
password=$(openssl passwd -1 1234)
ssh root@123.45.6.7 "useradd -p $password newuser"
```

Is there something that I miss? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Passing passwords on the command-line is a bad idea because other users may see the command-line arguments. See heemayl's answer for that. Beyond that, this sounds like an [XY Problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271411). What are you actually trying to achieve? What's the point of an account password that nobody knowns (or is supposed to know)? If the point is to create an account that doesn't accept log-ins via password just set no password at all which will leave password-based log-in disabled as Ubuntu's default policy.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is a classic quoting issue.

**Problem:** Without any quoting or double quoting the command substitution (`$()`) and variable expansion (the `$`s in the hashed password returned by `openssl` are being treated as variable indicator) are being done in the local environment, not on the remote shell.

**Solution:** use single quotes around the `useradd` command used with `ssh` on the local shell to prevent the command substitution and variable expansion on local environment, let the expansions take place on the remote non-login, non-interactive shell:

```
ssh root@123.45.6.7 'useradd -p "$(openssl passwd -1 1234)" newuser'
```

Note the quotings.

**Security issues:**

- SSH `root` login should be disabled, if you must have it enabled only key-based authentication should be allowed
- MD5 is already broken, and without a salt you are subjected to simple Rainbow table attack (does not even need brute forcing/dictionary attack); `openssl passwd` does generate a random salt though. Anyway, you should really consider using SHA-2 with salt-ing
- Passwords passed as arguments to commands might be visible to other processes in the (remote) system; this depends on how your `procfs` is mounted (look at `hidepid`), and if the command is rewriting itself (it this case presumably it does not)

Comment: Works like a charm, and thank you for the additional information!

Comment: the md5crypt password hash does have a salt...

Comment: @ilkkachu MD5 is not a secure hash. If you're interested, run a search on [security.se]. _Really_ you should use a compounded algorithm or cryptographic library, but SHA-2 is significantly better than MD5.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 yes, that's well known, doesn't change the fact that the information in this answer is incorrect. :)

Comment: @wizzwizz4, the password hash ([md5crypt](http://phk.freebsd.dk/sagas/md5crypt.html)) supported by [`crypt(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html) in Linux and marked with the `$1$` identifier is not the same as the plain MD5 hash algorithm, in the same way as the `$5$` and `$6$` [password hashes](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/SHA-crypt.txt) aren't plain SHA-256 and SHA-512 either. The MD5-based method has a fixed number of iterations, which is the biggest issue with it.

Comment: ...and, on my system (Debian 8, Openssl 1.0.1t-1), `openssl passwd -1` generates a random salt quite fine. It's the part between the second and third dollar signs.

Comment: @ilkkachu strange... I vaguely remember it wasn't generating any salt on my 14.04, that's why I have mentioned the without-salt thing...Off to bed now, will check the first thing tomorrow...

Comment: According to the man page on Ubuntu 16.04 the `openssl passwd` command only supports three algorithms. `1.` The original DES based crypt password hash, which is broken. `2.` The MD5 password hash, which is not yet broken, but has limited protection of weak passwords. `3.` An Apache variant of one of the former, which is not widely used and probably not much stronger. Of those three I would by far prefer MD5. Besides the worst problem with the command in your answer isn't the choice of hash, but rather that it makes the plaintext password visible in a command line on the server side.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 AIUI md5 has broken collision resistance but when it comes to preimage attacks there are only computationally infeasible attacks known.

Comment: Another security issue with this answer is it passes the password on the command line. Command line arguments may not be secret.

Comment: @PeterGreen Fair point, edited.

Answer (score 7):

As @heemayl noted, the MD5 password hash algorithm is aged, and current systems the newer SHA-2 based password hashes, that have a customisable work factor. But the OpenSSL command line tool doesn't seem to support those.

[The `chpasswd` utility](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/chpasswd.8.html), however, will allow you to change the password of a user according to the system settings.

This should allow you to create the new user and change their password on the remote end.

```
echo "newuser:newpass" | ssh root@123.45.6.7 'useradd newuser; chpasswd'
```

`chpasswd` takes the username and password from stdin, not the command line. This is actually an advantage since command line arguments are visible for all other processes on the system, so if run `openssl passwd` on the remote, the password would be momentarily visible to all processes on the system.

I'm not sure if there is a ready-made command line utility for generating password hashes known by the system `crypt(3)` function. Perl has the [`crypt` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/crypt.html) builtin, but a proper salt would still need to be generated.